# Vue js router: how to change or update URL query on click event

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to change/update the router query on click event in my navigation. But no matter what I do, the click event don't change the query in URL.

But in the vue in-component guard "beforeRouteUpdate" I get the new parameters if I console.log(to.query.scrollto);

Maybe someone have an idea or a better solution how I can fix this?

This is my intention:

> myhomepage.de/?scrollto=about
>   myhomepage.de/?scrollto=contact
>   myhomepage.de/otherpage/?scrollto=about
>   myhomepage.de/anotherpage/?scrollto=service
>   ...

These are my settings:

Router settings:

```
export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
base: __dirname,
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Page
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        component: NotFound
    }]
```

})

My navigation links:

```
a(href="" @click.prevent="updateNav(item.key)") {{item.title}}
```

In my methods:

```
updateNav(query) {
    var data = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
    data['scrollto'] = query;
    this.$router.push({name: 'home', query : data });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm this should work I think... do you get any errors perhaps?

Comment: No, I get no errors. All URLs with names directly after **/** for example /section?scrollto=contact work but not /?scrollto=contact. Maybe a config bug?

Comment: I doubt it's a config bug. could you `console.log(query)`? and what's after `...` in `updateNav`? Or perhaps remove `base` from `router` and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, it was a config bug in the vue router and in "beforeRouteUpdate". Problem has been solved! Thanks

Comment: @MimmoC., please post an answer and close the question.